# how to call all Google font CSS under specific font face

Tags: html, css, fonts

Can I call all the CSS of google font API under specific font-face?

I have here "Quattrocento Sans" that has 8 different font-style, the link below only call the CSS which font-style is only normal,

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

This second link call 400italic style:

```
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

However I like to call all the CSS which contains all 8 different styles with single link only.

So I'm thinking Something like this: Using ( * ) all

```
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans:*' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Is there any idea how to call all the CSS for this?

Comment: I hope when you search your font in `https://www.google.com/fonts` site, it will give option to add all the font with script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example:
standart:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

@import:

```
 `@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext);`
```

javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Quattrocento+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic:latin,latin-ext' ] }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
          '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })(); </script>
```

use: `font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;`

Comment: How about like this? Making the font more dynamic, Example I call a particular font in my link and not knowing all the font-style available for the font-face.

Comment: what do you mean the font size? its dynamic change?
the fact that this method is convenient for connecting web fonts, although you can yourself through special converters to convert the dates you specific fonts in web fonts and then connect to your site

Comment: I guess this one is more closer! Thankyou :D this safe's my time

Answer (score 1):

Don't Include Separate links:

- Instead again Go to the google font
- Open Quattrocento Sans font
- Add Whatever weight and style you need for that font
- And, add this code to your website

Link will be like following:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as an example:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800italic|Roboto:400,500,900|Oswald:400,300|Lato:400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

That way you can gather them all in one specific link.

Comment: What if the family will be on dynamic? something like this:           <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=$var_font:*' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>   :and example not knowing the different font-style available

Comment: I don't sincerely know if Google Fonts provide that kind of a solution, and it seems like a lot of work to be done, that is in my opinion totally unnecessary for this kind of a task, since all the fonts follow the same rule with weight and style attributes.

Comment: @GarfieldBesa, that is a different issue, not reflected at all in your question. Please accept one of the correct answers to the question you asked, and ask a new question about the more complicated issue (which might have a solution in Google APIs, using JavaScript).